# Nested dependency graph (DGML) in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependencies, dgml

I need to generate detailed dependency information of a .NET project. Integrated dependency graph is a great tool, it can even generate an XML file called DGML, which can be later opened and navigated.

This works great if source code is available during the navigation.

Unfortunatelly, I have access to source code only to generate this DGML file (or whatever I need) and must be able to broswe it offline, without access to source code.

Is it possible to generate a detailed, nested DGML file for the solution and be able to navigate as deep as needed? I could only geenrate and offline navigate a single level of this graph or a single node.

Is it possible to get this information in am anternative form (matrix, numbers, etc) and not only visually, in addition to the graphical representation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not possible with Visual Studio.  It only stores so much information in the .dgml file (edit it with XML editor to see it), and has to reference the source code for deeper navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course manually expand every node using "select all" followed by "+" and repeat a few times to get as deep as you want.  Now you have a massive DGML file that you can share with others (it should compress nicely if you zip it).